# JavaScript How to declare 16 length array with default 0 value quick?

Tags: javascript, arrays

`let array1 = Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);`
how to make like this array with shortest way ? is it possible to make shorter way ?
thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.fill()` method:

```
let array1 = new Array(16).fill(0);
```

As its name suggests, it fills the array with some desired value.